# Web Worker 20x worse performance

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I cannot seem to find a definite answer anywhere.

I have very simple POC that calculates same function in sync and async fashion.

Worker.js

```
onmessage = function(e) {
  var s = new Date().getTime();
  i = 0;
  var avg = Math.random();
  while ( i < e.data ){
    avg = (avg + Math.random()) / 2 ;
    i++;
  }
  var d = new Date().getTime();
  console.log( 'Duration ' + (d - s) );
  postMessage( avg );
}
```

Index.html

```
<script>
var mw = new Worker("worker.js");

mw.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('Worker says: ' + e.data);
  };

function av ( j ){
  var s = new Date().getTime();
  i = 0;
  var avg = Math.random();
  while ( i < j ){
    avg = (avg + Math.random()) / 2 ;
    i++;
  }
  var d = new Date().getTime();
  console.log( 'Result is ' + avg );
  console.log( 'Duration ' + (d - s) );
}



function runSync(){
  av( 100000000 );
}
function runAsync(){
  mw.postMessage( 100000000 );
}

</script>

  <a href="#" onClick="runSync()" /> Run Sync </a>

  <a href="#" onClick="runAsync()" /> Run Async </a>
```

On my 4 core MacBook this generates:

```
Result is 0.47398200501358567
Duration 985
Duration 23187
Worker says: 0.7422913957976759
```

As you can see web worker takes 20x longer to process. What is the explanation for this? Other related posts suggested garbage collection and heap, but then found the culprit to be some API issue. I am keen to understand what workers are and isn't. Do they have some odd performance penalty when garbage collector runs? If so, how do you manage memory in a way you would avoid such bottlenecks?

Comment: It might not be important, but I notice the functions are not exactly identical. The worker version uses `e.data` while the main thread one `j`. Also would be good to know what browser you ran this in.

Comment: Using `e.data` is the culprit, if you cache it in a variable it runs just about as fast as the inlined script (in Chrome at least).

Comment: @robertklep you are correct! Why is this causing so much trouble? Is iterating thru event grows the stack somehow? n.b. this ran on Chrome.

Comment: If you found a solution to your question, you should make an answer and accept that and not edit the question.

Comment: @Rob there is no answer yet though..

Comment: @Dzh Then why did you put "fixed" in the title and then say you had the solution?

Comment: Because I've got the solution from comments. Write an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Dzh: that still doesn't mean you put the answer (however it was derived) in the question. Feel free to add that as an answer yourself; if you feel you can't take credit for it you could make it a *Community Wiki* post.

Answer (score 0):

They are not exactly the same function, you are acessing `e.data` in the worker, wich its a lot slower than accesing the cached `j` directly, if you change that, they should take about the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
onmessage = function(e) {
  var j = e.data;
  var s = new Date().getTime();
  i = 0;
  var avg = Math.random();
  while ( i < j ){
    avg = (avg + Math.random()) / 2 ;
    i++;
  }
  var d = new Date().getTime();
  console.log( 'Worker Duration ' + (d - s) );
  postMessage( avg );
}
```

And Result:

> *Result is 0.3949881073856792*
>     *Duration 853*
>     *Worker Duration 847*
>     *Worker says: 0.2902113830870678*